# Tkinter button - import and run module

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I would like to run a python program (ex: program.py) when clicking a button in a tkinter window in a separate program.  However, when I import the class from the module, it runs.  How do I get the button to run the module when clicked? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Other Module to Run (program.py):

```
class sampleProgram():
    def DoSomething():
        print('Do Something')
```

Module with tkinter button:

```
from program import DoSomething

class Window(Frame)
    def __init__(self,master = None):
        <Stuff In Window>

    def addWidgets(self):
        <Widgets To Add>

    def init_window(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        RunButton = Button(self, text="Run", command=<**What Goes Here To Run sampleProgram?**>)
```

Comment: With the shown code (and assuming you mean `class` (all lowercase) instead of `Class`) there isn't a problem with importing the `program` module as it just defines a class when imported.

Comment: @BlackJack - Thanks for your response.  I have edited the question but was able to make it work based on the original response from @ReblochonMasque.  Can you explain your comment about using a `staticmethod` rather than placing the functions in a class?  I appreciate the chance to learn a better way to write it!

Comment: If a method doesn't take the instance it is called on as first argument then it isn't really a method and this should be made clear with [staticmethod()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod). Otherwise you can't call it on an instance. Also it's a code smell to put functions/”static methods” in a class.  On rare occasions it makes sense but only if you can explain why exactly it isn't simply a normal function instead of a function stuffed into a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `DoSomething` on the `sampleProgram` class; for this, you must import it.

```
Class sampleProgram():
    def DoSomething():              # <--- this is a staticmethod
        print('Do Something')
```

Module with tkinter button:

```
from program import sampleProgram   # <--- import the class sampleProgram

Class Window(Frame)
    def __init__(self,master = None):
        <Stuff In Window>

    def addWidgets(self):
        <Widgets To Add>

    def init_window(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        RunButton = Button(self, text="Run", command=sampleProgram.DoDomething)
```

You bind the `sampleProgram.DoDomething` staticmethod to the `runButton command`; when the button is clicked, this command is called.

Comment: `DoSomething` isn't a class method. You need to decorate it with `classmethod` to become one and it has to take the class object as first argument. So maybe you actually want a `staticmethod`. Which then begs the question why functions are moved into a ”class”.

Answer (score 1):

`from program import DoSomething`

On the command for that button you can simply call `def DoSomething()`

`RunButton = Button(self, text="Run", command=DoSomething)`